# Flask-Migrate script not doing applying changes to Postgres database

Tags: postgresql, docker, flask, flask-migrate

I have made some recent changes to my models in my Flask project. I tried to apply these changes to my Postgres DB, but the script doesn't seem to have any effect. When I run the upgrade it says

```
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.runtime.migration] Running upgrade  -> ba60ca569e9f, empty message
```

but nothing changes in the DB. I dropped the database and recreated it and still nothing happened. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`Context impl SQLiteImpl.` is a strong hint. My DB URI is determined by `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URI') or 'sqlite:///'`. When I ran my project in my Docker-compose environment it worked because the `DATABASE_URI` was getting set correctly in a Dockerfile. When I ran it on my local environment it was not working. I could have run it on my server container and it should have worked.

I fixed this by correctly setting my DATABASE_URI to `export DATABASE_URI=postgres://{USERNAME}:{PASSWORD}@127.0.0.1:5432/debateit`. This let my local environment connect to the Postgres DB rather than the local SQLite.